# how to configure apache for phabricator

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, phabricator

My operating system is Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed Apache using `apt-get install`. In the directory `/etc/apache2`, there is no `httpd.conf` which is used while configuring Apache by the [instruction](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/)

please help

Answer (score 6):

1) Go to /etc/apache2/sites-available. Delete all *.conf files.

2) Create phabricator.conf file here with following content:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    # Change this to the domain which points to your host.
    ServerName yourservername

    # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it
    # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.
    #
    # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!
    DocumentRoot /path/to/phabricator/webroot

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]

    <Directory "/path/to/phabricator/webroot">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

3) make sure that you enter correct path for your phabricator directory in phabricator.conf.

4) Go to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. Delete all symlinks.

5) Execute the following commands:

```
sudo a2ensite phabricator
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: note that moving the files into another directory works as well as deleting them

Answer (score 0):

You may read this document that said where are the files for different versions and distros http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout.

Also get in mind that if you have many servers you will need to configure the server configuration found in apache2/sites-availables/default.conf, if you use the default server change it; if not, create a new one based on default.conf.

It could be good if you introduce yourself with apache server, for example read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
updatedb
```

then

```
locate httpd.conf
```